# Override Introspection Endpoint Access token validation - Identity Server 3

Tags: access-token, identityserver3

I would like to add some functionality in the Access token validation (Introspection Endpoint) method of the Identity Server 3.
How can I implement an override for this method?

A sample of this process would be the best.

Comment: instead of an override, have you seen this https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/ICustomTokenValidator.cs ? - you could implement this and register it at startup (via the factory)